# Date of questions on stackoverflow is not correct

Tags: bug, date-format

I don't know if this is considered as a bug, but I've noticed on Stackoverflow that questions that have been posted like two days ago, still have the title "yesterday" on them, eg :

[Regex to remove prefix of a pattern (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690016/regex-to-remove-prefix-of-a-pattern-r)

Regards

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115974/possible-bug-in-sidebar-question-asked-date